# Error replacing IndexedDB entries in Safari 8.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari, indexeddb

I am writing an unit test for an IndexedDb Angular module for all browsers with Karma and Jasmine.

Every browser gives me the expected behavior (even IE 10+) except Safari 8.0.

In the unit test I create three objects to add to the database as an array. `dbHandler` is the indexedDb handling object. There is already an element inside the storage from the test before that with primary key 1.

```
var entries = [
  { _id: 1, hello3: "test3" },
  { newObject: true, trueness: false },
  { name: "other object", attributes: ['a', 'b', 'c'] }
];

dbHandler.put(entries).then(function(data){
  expect(data.length).toEqual(3);

  expect(data[0]).toEqual(1);
  expect(data[1]).toEqual(2);
  expect(data[2]).toEqual(3);

  window.clearInterval(interval);
  done();
});
```

`_id` is my primary key for the storage, so the first entry should overwrite the existing entry.

The `put` method of the IndexedDb handler looks like this:

```
IndexedDbHandler.prototype.put = function (data) {
  var deferer = $q.defer();
  var self = this;

  this.connect().then(function(){
    // create singleton array with data, if data is no array
    if (!(data instanceof Array)) {
      data = [data];
    }
    var addedDataCount = 0;
    var dataLength = data.length;
    var idList = [];

    var transaction = IndexedDbHandler._db.transaction([self._tableName], 'readwrite');


    transaction.oncomplete = function() {
      deferer.resolve(idList);
    };

    [...]

    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(self._tableName);

    // Add data with _id to the database
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      objectStore.put(data[i]).onsuccess = function(e) {
        idList.push(e.target.result);
      }
    }
  });

  [...]

  return deferer.promise;
}
```

This method returns a promised array with the primary keys of the saved store entries.

In every browser but Safari 8.0 the returned array is `[1,2,3]`. Safari returns `[1,1,2]`, completely ignoring the already set ID in the previous test.

When I'm removing the `_id` from the first `entries` object, all browsers return the same values.

Is this a Safari bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I know I'm not supposed to post a link on SO as the answer, and feel free to vote this down, but my time is a bit short and figured actually helping you would be appreciated even if it isn't the "SO way" - http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/9/25/IndexedDB-on-iOS-8--Broken-Bad.